# URL issue with subdomains

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, subdomain

I'm currently developing a website with several domains and only 1 domain is giving a weird bug..

for example;
website/maindomain (if maindomain / link is same as parent it doesnt show == website/)

```
website/subdomain1/subpage1/subpage2
website/subdomain2/subpage3/subpage2
website/subdomain3/subpage3/subpage2
```

(this list goes on for some while)

when i go from; website/subdomain1/ to the first subpage there's no issue. when i go to subpage2 the issue appears.. and it's only on 1 subdomain that this issue appears!!

the link of the subdomain is 'subdomain1', but i get an issuewith invalid url..
when i type the link of the subdomain and append 'en' (subdomain1en) than i proceed to the page..

the part of my htacces which does this magic trick is as follow;

```
RewriteRule ^(?[-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php?subdomein=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?([-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php?subdomein=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?([-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php?subdomein=$1&page=$2&sub=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?([-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php?subdomein=$1&page=$2&sub=$3&sub-sub=$4 [L,QSA]
```

Would be nice if someone can help me

Comment: Have you tried reversing the order of your rules?

Comment: Yes, i've played with it a long while xD and on other sites we created which got subdomains it works flawless, so i'm wondering what the big issue is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you do your ordering this way.

```
RewriteRule ^/?([-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php?subdomein=$1&page=$2&sub=$3&sub-sub=$4 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?([-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php?subdomein=$1&page=$2&sub=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?([-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php?subdomein=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(?[-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php?subdomein=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I've tried this, but than i get an internal server error :o

Comment: What does your error log say once you get the 500 error. Check the log so you why it's giving you the error.

Comment: The error i gained was as follow.. xDInternal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: I said your **error log** not the error the user sees. Again check the `error_log`. What's funny is that the error you just pasted told you to do the same thing. `More information about this error may be available in the server error log`

Comment: Server Error log was empty somehow, we've fixed the issue, somewhere with creating the page there went something wrong.. so we made a new check in it with tons more sub-sub-sub-etc.. xD